# IndexError: list index out of range - {0, 1} Knapsack Problem

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

This has code has been working fine for a few weeks but hit an error earlier and I can't figure out why. The error is coming from the look in sack function at the line "if dp[z][i][w] - dp[z][i-1][w - player_costs[i-1]] == player_scores[i-1]:" and 'i' is hitting 0 and it shouldn't be right? I am assuming there's an issue with what it's searching for and the way that dp is formed.

Any help would be really appreciated, let me know if you need more info? Super stuck.

```
def knapsack(num_items, weight, count, values, weights, add):
    dp = [[[0] * (weight + 1) for _ in range(num_items + 1)] for _ in range(count + 1)]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        values[i] = values[i] + add
    for z in range(1, count + 1):
        for y in range(1, num_items + 1):
            for x in range(weight + 1):
                if weights[y - 1] <= x:
                    dp[z][y][x] = max(dp[z][y - 1][x],
                                      dp[z - 1][y - 1][x - weights[y - 1]] + values[y - 1])
                else:
                    dp[z][y][x] = dp[z][y - 1][x]
    return dp

def look_in_sack(result, budget, count, num_items, player_costs, player_scores):
    elements = []
    dp = result
    w = budget
    i = num_items
    z = count
    while (i>0 and len(elements)<count): 

        if dp[z][i][w] - dp[z][i-1][w - player_costs[i-1]] == player_scores[i-1]:
            #the element 'i' is in the knapsack
            elements.append(i)
            i = i-1
            w -= player_costs[i]
        else:
            i = i-1
    return elements

result = knapsack(num_items, budget, count, player_scores, player_costs, add_this)
elements = look_in_sack(result, budget, count, num_items, player_costs, player_scores)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.
Your posted code defines two functions and quits without calling either one.

Comment: I suggest You use readable variable names not one letter names since they are much harder to read therefore also harder to debug and it is a mess in general. so use proper variable names (also use `snake_case` (which You do))

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I'm quite new to all this. I can't give the data as its very large but I've updated with the function calls. Hope that helps? Thanks for getting back to me anyway